# Introducing a delay in OpenCV::VideoCapture

Tags: qt, opencv

I have a class Camera inheriting from cv::VideoCapture, which its core method is to convert a cv::Mat that I get from a live stream to a QImage :

```
QImage Camera::getFrame() {
    if(isOpened()) {
        cv::Mat image;
        (*this) >> image;
        cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB);
        return QImage((uchar*) image.data, image.cols, image.rows, image.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    }
    else return QImage();
}
```

And an encapsulating class CameraDelayedView which calls this method and adds a delay :

```
void CameraDelayedView::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *evt) {
    if(cam != NULL) {
        buffer.enqueue(cam->getFrame());

        if(buffer.size() > delay*fps) {
            setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(buffer.dequeue()));
        }
    }
}
```

I can see with a delay of 5seconds that the initial display of the video is delayed, but after that it runs smoothly. It nearly seems like the images are still somehow linked to the live feed through pointers (or QQeueue is not a proper FIFO but I doubt it)... Is it so ?

If it is, this way I may give an answer to other people who are going through the same thing, and I would be interested in an efficient way of copying (or a more efficient of the above code). If not, I have no idea what's happening...

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mister Mystère

Answer (score 2):

The feed from the camera is queued in some sort of a buffer. I have struggled with this problem myself a while a go, solved it using a separate thread, which constantly takes the frames from the buffer, and if asked sends a frame to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so it's not that obvious. In order to keep it simple, would it work to simply copy the content itself of each frame? Sounds obvious to me that it would, but might as well be sure. If so, how should I copy image.data, is it bounded by a NULL character? You must have copied it, even using threads to be able to send them later, didn't you?

Comment: Well, I used threads with pure OpenCV. Just `cap>>mat;` in an infinite loop with some mutexes to extract `mat` if needed. I'd advise to not try to do it in one go, rather divide it into steps, like emptying the buffer, getting the latest frame, sending it to qt...

Comment: Indeed, I am trying to separate OpenCV from Qt at each frame, translating it in a QImage before beinf stored. Maybe there is a more independant way to do it, since they are still linked this way (probably through image.data).

Answer (score 2):

All cameras need a time of *warming-up* after the `STREAM-ON` (in v4l terminology) request, which can range from a few milliseconds to some seconds.

If you cannot afford such delay for the first frame, you'd better leave the camera on.  Then, you might find yourself getting old frames.  In such case you would need to **flush** the camera at the beginning. That is: quickly discarding every available [stale] frame while there are such.  (you need to be able to know whether there are new images without blocking)

A different approach involves leaving a thread consuming those images, and using them only when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realise now I may have not made myself clear on my aim: as crazy as it my sound, I want a settable delay in the feed from the camera. So the warmup is not a big deal for me as long as it's within the delay. However this is good to know for non-delayed views, which I also have.

Comment: Then you are talking about the "framerate" setting, which all cameras should offer. I have seen cheap cameras only offer 30 fps.  In this case you could have a thread set a "latest image" image buffer in case you are interested in it.  If noone read it, it is simply lost.  Then, from your thread you read a image (which would come immediately, since you are just reading an already received image), and wait the time you need.

Comment: The framerate should stay "smooth" at 30fps (max). This is really like stopping a road for some time getting nearly a traffic jam, and then letting it flow by itself: this is only a delay at the start, and so images received should be what's been seen one delay ago. But for the last part, reading an image and waiting the time needed is basically what I try to do in the above code, it just doesn't work...